# bind returns address in use even if no connection is established

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a c++ code in which I am trying to establish a connection on a socket. But I firstly need to check if a connection already exist on a given port, and if it exists I need to close the connection. I have the code below and my problem is that when checking if the port is already connected it returs that it is even if connect has failed previously.

```
connected = false;
int sockfd;
void conn(int port) {
   struct sockaddr_in addr;
   addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   addr.sin_port   = htons(port);
   .....
   int sockfd_t;
   if ( (sockfd_t = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
       cout << "Error opening socket_test " << endl;
       return;
   }
   // check if address already in use
   if (bind(sockfd_t, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        if(errno == EADDRINUSE) {
        cout << "address in use: bind fail, port=" << port << endl;
    }
        // do something - close the connection if already connected
    }
    else {
        cout << "bind ok, port=" << port << endl;
    }
    close(sockfd_t);

    if ( (sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
       cout << "Error opening socket " << endl;
       return;
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &adresse, sizeof(adresse))) {
        cout << "Error connecting" << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return;
    }

    connected = true;
}

int main() {
    int port=3590;
    while (!connected) {
       conn(port);
    }
    cout << "CONNECTED";
    // ..........
}
```

After running the program this is the output printed:

```
bind ok, port=3590;
Error connecting
bind ok, port=3590;
Error connecting
address in use: bind fail, port=3590 //???
CONNECTED!
```

I don't know why on the 5-th line of the print it displays "address in use:..." as the connect fails the first two times?

Comment: Are you using SO_REUSADDR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a misconception about what these socket operations do.

> *But I firstly need to check if a connection already exist on a given port, and if it exists I need to close the connection.*

1. `bind()` gives a socket a **local address**, rather than having anything to do with checking if a remote address you are trying to connect to is accessible.
2. `connect()` connects the socket to a **remote address**.
3. When connecting a socket as a client (which is what I think you are trying to do), you don't need to check if there is already a connection, remote server can handle **multiple incoming client connections** to the same port. Binding is usually only important for servers.
4. if you don't bind before connecting, a socket will be assigned a random local port.

So, if you are a **client**, you do:

1. `socket()`
2. `connect()`

If you are a **server**, you do:

1. `socket()`
2. `bind()`
3. `listen()`

In your own question, the output makes sense when there is no server listening, but then a server comes online.

1. First two times, you bind a socket and it's successful, because nobody is using it to listen, then you fail to connect, because you just bound, and did not start a server (by calling `listen()`).
2. Then a real server on the same host binds that socket and starts listening, therefore you can't bind that port anymore (it fails), but you can connect, because the server is listening.

Comment: A client can `bind()` to a specific local IP/Port before calling `connect()`.  Some protocols require that.  If `bind()` is not called beforehand, `connect()` performs an implicit `bind()` internally.  Also, the simple act of calling `bind()` will lock a local IP/Port for use for a period of time after the socket is closed. That could also explain why the `EADDRINUSE` error occurs.